# Add firebase users using social login to user database?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Does Firebase automatically add users that login via a social provider like facebook to the firebase Authentication / User database?

In other words if Christine signs in via Facebook, does firebase also store her email address, first name, etc. in the Authentication / User database that she would be stored in if she signed up via the regular signup form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the Firebase Authentication list then yes. See here =>
[Authentication database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns8Ia.png)

But if you want to save some user data in the realtime or firestore database you have to do it yourself. Best way to do that in my opinion is with Firebase Functions but you could also do it in the client after a successful register/login.

This is a simplified version of the function I would use in the client directly after login. I'd usually add a bunch of custom properties like last login, etc..

```
writeUserToDB(user: User) {
  this.db.object('users/'+ user.uid).valueChanges().take(1).subscribe( val => {
    let newUser = val == null ? user : val;      
    this.db.object('users/' + newUser.uid ).update(newUser)
  });
}
```

Also some basic rules for the /users node.

```
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
     }
```

Comment: Yes - The Authentication Database.  So if someone logs in via facebook their profile is added to the Authentication Base?  I would not want to duplicate it ... I assume I can also backup and save the Authentication Database or transfer the data at some point if needed?

Comment: Yes, all users would be added to this database regardless of the Sign-In Method used. Regarding backup or transfering of this list Im not to sure thats a straight-forward task. I remember reading about some dev who did that but he had to contact Firebase support to be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

When a user signs in to Firebase Authentication with a social provider, their profile is automatically stored in Firebase Authentication itself. This information (including their [email address](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#email)) is available through the Firebase Authentication SDKs, including the server-side [Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users).

No data is automatically stored in the Firebase Database. If you want to do that, you can easily do it yourself though.

Comment: OK - So just pull the user profile out of the authentication and save it to the database...Do you have any pointers that provide some hints as to how to go about this?  Just getting started with Firebase ....

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-authentication%5d%20store%20in%20database for some great questions and answers to get started with.

Comment: Now thats what I call some links!  Thanks!  Do you know whether it's true that its hard to backup or transfer the Authentication database as Davio is indicating?

Comment: Whether it's hard is subjective. Here are the docs on importing/exporting users though: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth

Comment: Brilliant - it sounded like we had to contact customer service in order to be able to do this before, but now we can simply do it on the command line.  Start to get more and more impressed with firebase.  Almost too easy :).  Thanks again for all the great tips!

Comment: It indeed used to be a "mail support" thing, while we were figuring out the best format. After that was clear, it was quickly automated and put into the CLI. Thanks for using Firebase!